# Flink SQL-CLi: bring header records

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, sqlclient

I'm new with flink sql cli and I want to create a sink from my kafka cluster.

I've read the documentation and as I understand de headers are a map<STRING, BYTE> types and through them are all the important information.

When I'm using de sql-cli I try to create a sink table following this command:

```
CREATE TABLE KafkaSink (
`headers` MAP<STRING, BYTES> METADATA     
) WITH (
      'connector' = 'kafka',
      'topic' = 'MyTopic', 
      'properties.bootstrap.servers' ='LocalHost',
      'properties.group.id' = 'MyGroypID',
      'scan.startup.mode' = 'earliest-offset',
      'value.format' = 'json'
    );
```

But when I try to read the data with select * from KafkaSink limit 10; It returns me null records

[image]

I've tried to run queries like

```
select headers.col1 from a limit 10;
```

And also, I've tried to create the sink table with different structures at selecting columns part:

```
...
`headers` STRING
...
...
`headers` MAP<STRING, STRING>
...
...
`headers` ROW(COL1 VARCHAR, COL2 VARCHAR...)
...
```

But it returns me nothing, however when I bring the offset columns from kafka cluster it brings me the offset but no the headers.

Can someone explain me my error?

I want to create a kafka sink with flink sql cli

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, as I could see it, when I tried to change to

```
'format' = 'debezium-json'
```

I could see in a better way the json.
I follow the json schema, in my case was

```
{
"data": {...},
"metadata":{...}
}
```

So instead of bringing the header i'm bringing the data with all the columns that i need, the data as a string and the columns as for example
data.col1, data.col2

In order to see the records, just with a

```
select 
      json_value(data, '$.Col1') as Col1 
from Table;
```

it works!